# Formatting an export file from access to excel with conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Needing assistance on performing a format check. Ok so what I have now is a button on my access form that exports the results into a new blank Excel file when clicked. What I am trying to accomplish now is add some code that checks if Fields 6-10 added together <> field 5 throughout the WHOLE dataset then performing conditional formatting and highlight the ones that aren't the same as yellow.

Once this is in place, Then I would like a message box to appear and however many items that are highlighted in the Excel file to appear within the list box msg. An example being there are (9) cells that are mismatched and need attention before an upload can be submitted!"

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim Excel_App As Excel.Application 'Creates Blank Excel File
Dim strTable As String ' Table in access
    Dim queryDelete As String 'SQL to delete records in local table
    Dim strAssigned As DAO.Recordset


    strTable = "Make_allUp" 'Access Table I am trying to copy
    Set Excel_App = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set dbs = CurrentDb

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strTable)

    Excel_App.Visible = True

Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
Set wkb = Excel_App.Workbooks.Add

Dim rg As Excel.Range
Dim i As Long
' Add the headings
For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
Next i

Set rg = wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1)
rg.CopyFromRecordset rs

' make pretty
rg.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit

If wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(5, 2) <> wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(6, 2) + wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(7, 2) + wkb.Sheets    (1).Cells(8, 2) + wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(9, 2) + wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(10, 2) Then
Format.Cells
****Okay above is what I am having troubles with. Just needing to somehow say if the vaule in field 6 + field 7 + field 8 + field 9 + field 10 <> field 5 Then
highlight those records yellow



Set rs = Nothing
Set wkb = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: There is no question that we could answer (see [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)).

Comment: It is in the ***** within the code above? Sorry just added it

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Access will not, and can not, format the export information.  It is possible to write Excel VBA code to format the cells in the target spreadsheet.  Also, it is possible to write code in Access VBA to write the Excel VBA code to format the cells and to have the code exported tot he spreadsheet.  In addition, it is also possible to open the spreadsheet where the information was exported and format the cells from within Ms. Access using Access VBA code.  But, as I know, you cannot get Access to format the information prior to, or during, the export process itself.